# Is Asp.NET MVC Not Suitable For N-Tier Architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

Firstly, I have a question which already I know the answer but I want to ask; 
Which one is manageable on HTML source?? Asp.NET Web Forms or Asp.NET MVC??

My second and important question;
Think a project which is big and expandable web project.. You sell something and control your agents with this project. You can give XML for your product range, and you would be able to add new products.. What does "Asp.NET Web Forms is more suitable for N-Tier Architecture and Asp.NET MVC is not" mean??

Comment: It all depends on how you structure things. Layered spaghetti ("lasagna code") is possible with any framework...

Comment: Short answer (in my opinion and based on my experience): It's completely suitable. I'm curious where the statement "Asp.NET Web Forms is more suitable for N-Tier Architecture and Asp.NET MVC is not" came from and why you are giving it credence.

Comment: I heard it on a job interview and he works a company which is prominent on software sector.. I dont agree with him but I want research..

Comment: I think that was a trick question, asked to see how you responded to such bold statements and perhaps to test your knowledge on both frameworks, trying to provoke a healthy discussion. What did you reply?

Comment: My company need coworker and they try to make us rent outsource developer.. I think they dont have any developer who knows MVC..

Comment: Anyone that tells you that MVC is not suitable for n-tier but WebForms is, is either joking, trying to goad you into arguing, or doesn't know what they're talking about.  n-tier can and has been written in both.  There is really no difference here (some people want to claim separation of concerns makes MVC better, but in reality MVC is just one tier (the presentation tier), anything that goes on outside that tier has nothing to do with MVC or WebForms for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that MVC is just as suited if not more so than Web Forms. Given the much clearer separation of the different parts in the MVC framework it lends itself very well to creating a solid N-tier solution. But with anything, if care is not taken in the implementation it really doesn't matter what framework you are using.